# Cargar datos MySql PHP en Ionic con Wamp64

Tags: php, mysql, json, ionic3, wamp

He instalado y configurado el servidor **Wamp64** y he conseguido que cargue el localhost y phpadmin sin problema. También accede desde localhost a los proyectos, abriendo la carpeta raíz de los mismos y está el símbolo de color verde.

He creado todo el proyecto de *Ionic* dentro de la carpeta *wamp64/www/nombre_proyecto*. Los ficheros php y la base de datos creada con phpmyAdmin la almaceno también dentro del proyecto.

Si ejecuto **localhost/mi_proyecto/data.php**, me carga los datos de *json* sin problema, pero al ejecutar *ionic serve*, carga el título en la pantalla pero la tabla sale vacía.

Creé varios proyectos distintos y todos fallan en lo mismo. Se lee el *json* en el navegador pero no cargan los datos del *data.php* al compilar *Ionic*. Ya no se me ocurre qué hacer :(

El último ejemplo de prueba es éste: 
http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Agrega el código que usas para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: La última prueba la hice reproduciendo tal cual el ejemplo de este blog, no he puesto el código porque es exactamente el mismo, siguiendo los pasos, y cambiando sólo los parámetros de acceso a la base de datos .sql (usuario: root, paswork:"")  http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien más le pasa... en las cabeceras de los ficheros .php hay que añadir lo siguiente:

**header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type' );**

Ahora cargan los datos por duplicado pero ¡¡cargan!! Mil gracias por leerme y por este foro que nos hace la vida más fácil ;)